# how to make chapter and section titles at the beginning of pages be on the same line?

Tags: titlesec, report

Consider test case:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thechapter}{10pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{10pt}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Test0}\newpage
\chapter{Test1}\newpage
\section{Test1.1}\newpage
\end{document}
```

Even after setting vertical space before title to `0pt` with `titlespacing`, chapter and section titles at the beginning of pages still aren't on the same line:

[image]

This can be a result of `report` use, at least in `article` this difference is about 1pt.

Is it possible to set vertical space before chapter title to 0 or remove it? Instead of using `titlespacing` with negative values?

Comment: Related but not identical: [Unwanted extra space before \vspace* at top of page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/247513) (since the vertical space before `\chapter` is used in `\vspace*`)

Comment: You may find answers in these questions (seems like a duplicate) https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59389/219947 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17299/219947

Comment: @Imran this is very likely duplicate. sometimes it's difficult to understand what to search for, when you only have the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [Gonzalo Medina's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59392/219947) or [Danie Els'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17338/219947) answer, the vertical space above the chapter title is 'almost' removed. According to Gonzalo Medina's answer:

> The internal command `\ttl@mkchap@i` adds some vertical spacing to the chapter titles, so you need to remove this space; this can be done by commenting out the line responsible for this space (the one  marked with % NEW in the code):

Output after applying Gonzalo Medina's solution:
[image]
The red line indicates page margin.

After removing the vertical space by commenting out the `\vspace*`, there is still a small space left. The reason behind this small space (see [struts](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Rules_and_Struts)) being left is described in the [titlesec documentation](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf). From the documentation:

> The styles defined by `titlesec` insert some struts at certain places to make sure the vertical space is the same with relation with the baseline.

To remove this strut from the chapter title, the `\nostruts` macro can be used in the `\titleformat` of the chapter.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\makeatletter
\def\ttl@mkchap@i#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{%
  \ttl@assign\@tempskipa#3\relax\beforetitleunit
  %\vspace*{\@tempskipa}% NEW
  \global\@afterindenttrue
  \ifcase#5 \global\@afterindentfalse\fi
  \ttl@assign\@tempskipb#4\relax\aftertitleunit
  \ttl@topmode{\@tempskipb}{%
    \ttl@select{#6}{#1}{#2}{#7}}%
  \ttl@finmarks  % Outside the box!
  \@ifundefined{ttlp@#6}{}{\ttlp@write{#6}}}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\nostruts}{\thechapter}{10pt}{} %%\nostruts here
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{10pt}

%-------Shows page layout-------------------
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%-------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test0}\newpage
\chapter{Test1}\newpage
\section{Test1.1}\newpage
\end{document}
```

1st page:

[image: 1]

2nd page:

[image: 2]

3rd page:

[image: 3]

Notice that the strut is still present in the section title as we only removed it from the chapter title.

Comment: thank you, it works as it should. as a side effect it breaks setting vertical space before chapter title with `titlespacing`, which is probably expected